# What does 仕手を打つ mean?

Tags: meaning

> 「でも、やらなければならないのよ。襲撃の決断は突発的なものだったとしても、敵はこの場に至るまでに、こちらの逃げ道を周到に潰すように**仕手を打って**きた。その結果が、二〇〇回を超える士道の死よ」

What does the bold part mean? Does it mean “take measures”?

Comment: ここ（https://syosetu.org/novel/9452/84.html）では、「でも、やらなければならないのよ。襲撃の決断は突発的なものだったとしても、敵はこの場に至るまでに、こちらの逃げ道を周到に潰すように**手を**打ってきた。
その結果が200回を越える士道の死よ」になってますが。

Comment: @Chocolate Hi. I didn’t know there was an online version, but the paperback version is 仕手を打つ. So do you think 仕手を打つ is a typo?

Comment: Yeah, I think it is a typo.